# Using Python to SSH, with the known hosts from file, to extract result of a command

Tags: python, ssh

I want to connect to a remote host listed in `~/.ssh/config`, run a command (`ps` specifically) and extract the output.

Which is the simplest tool that can do all this?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `popen` to shell out to `ssh` proper?

Comment: Maybe because this isn't a very programmatic way?

Comment: @tdammers ITYM `Popen`, specifically `subprocess.Popen`. I hope you didn't mean `os.popen()`...

Comment: @glglgl: yeah, sure. The important part is the shellout, not how exactly you do it.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: ...and this is bad because...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), a python native ssh library.

A (very) basic example of how you'd use it (connection based on ssh-key):

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('127.0.0.1')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('date')

for line in stdout:
    print line,
print
```

Output:

```
Fri Nov 23 17:36:09 EET 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way to do this is with a 'while' loop in the command line - this assumes that you don't necessarily NEED to use Python...

For a file (hostlist.txt) that contains a list of host addresses:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do 
    ssh user1@$p ps
done < hostlist.txt
```

If you really wanted to use Python you could set-up a similar loop and possibly use Python's `subprocess` module to call ssh...

Comment: why not the recommended way of using the `subprocess` module?

Comment: @glglgl The recommended way of using the `subprocess` module should not be used for Python versions 2.4 and below (as it didn't exist then). Otherwise, I concede - `subprocess` seems more robust and useful than `os`. I have now amended the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do

```
def remote_ps(host):
    import subprocess
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', host, 'ps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
    return sp.wait(), out
```